# Recursion of redirect continues after .htaccess file is removed

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried to set a redirect using mod_rewrite, but this resulted in filename recursion.  I removed the .htaccess file, but it continues.  What is going on?

Comment: might be cached. restart apache

Comment: I have done, nothing changes.